# SAT, combinatorics, compactness

Tags: combinatorics, logic

Let $A$ be a propositional CNF formula, where each clause is limited to at most three literals. Let number of clauses in $A$ is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and number of variables of $A$ is equal to some $k$. Define function $F(n,k)$ to be equal to number $x$ if the following holds:

minimal $x$ such that
if each subset of $x$ clauses of $n$ clauses of $A$ is satisfiable, then $A$ is satisfiable.

Clearly $F(n,k)\leq n$.

The question is if there is a better estimate of the function $F$.

Thank you very much

Comment: When $k\geq n$, $F(n,k)=n$, even for $2$-SAT. In $3$-SAT, I expect you'll find $F(n,k)=n$ even for much smaller values of $k$, but I don't have an explicit example in mind.

Comment: The example with $k=n$ is $P_1 \wedge (\lnot P_1 \vee P_2) \wedge (\lnot P_2 \vee P_3) \wedge \dots \wedge \lnot P_n$.